# ImportError: No module named benchmark_util

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import

I write the following:

`import HPOlib.benchmark_util as benchmark_util`

And try to use function, how it is in example http://hpolib.readthedocs.io/en/development/manual.html#how-to-run-your-own-benchmarks:

`args, params = benchmark_util.parse_cli()`

But it raises exception:

`ImportError: No module named benchmark_util`

How can I import this module?

Comment: What example are you referring to?  What library is "HPOlib"?

Comment: I add the link. HPOlib is library which tunes hyperparameters of machine learning algorithms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The manual is out of synch with the source.
If you look at the source code, `benchmark_util` is under the `benchmarks` directory.

To do a direct import you'd need to do `import HPOlib.benchmarks.benchmark_util as benchmark_util`

For example, if you look at the [har6 source code](https://github.com/automl/HPOlib/blob/master/benchmarks/har6/har6.py), it uses `import HPOlib.benchmarks.benchmark_util as benchmark_util`